# Converting .tif to pdf/A 1.4 or 1.5

Tags: shell, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, tiff

Using a shell command I have been able to convert .tif files to pdf files. Unfortunately the outputed files are in pdf/A ver 1.3 and I need it to pdf/A v1.4 or 1.5.

This is my command (output in v1.3):

```
Convert test.tif test.pdf
```

I think the command is using imagemagick tool (which use ghostscript) to do the conversion

So I tried this ( still 1.3 but the pdf/A is not valid):

```
convert test.tif pdfa:test.pdf
```

Then I tried to convert the pdf 1.3 to 1.5 using ghostscript

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new-test1.5.pdf test.pdf
```

This work just fine.Do you think is possible to convert .tif file directly to .pdf 1.4 or 1.5 ?

I tried to check the gosthscript files but I was not able to do any modification leading to my excpected result.

Thank you for your help
RFlow

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated which version of PDF/A you require. If you need PDF/A-1a or PDF/A-1b then you **cannot** produce a PDF greater than PDF 1.3 as that is specifically forbidden by the specification.

Why do you need PDF 1.4 or 1.5 ? The PDF version is simply a statement of the minimum feature set used by this PDF file, PDF is forward-compatible, a PDF 1.4 consumer can also by definition read PDF 1.3 files. Since you started with TIFF I cannot see any way that your PDF file needs to be of a higher level than PDF 1.3

Your Ghostscript command line will produce a PDF file which states that it requires a consumer of at least level 1.5 (which is a lie ;-) but the resulting PDF will not be PDF/A compliant.

So you really need to explain why you need a PDF/A file, and why it has to be PDF version 1.4 or greater.

Comment: PDF/A-1 is based on PDF-1.4, not PDF-1.3.

Comment: What version of ImageMagick are you using? Perhaps a newer version of ImageMagick will produce a higher level version of PDF. I believe the latest versions of ImageMagick will support PDF 1.7

Comment: @KenS :  Thank you for your answer. The PDF files will be analyzed by a  Document Management System. The requirements are PDF/A-1b version 1.4 or 1.5. When I use the GS compatibility tool to 1.5 the documents are valid and the DMS accept it ( it was not the case in v1.3). I would like to automatically make the conversion from tiff file to good version of the pdf.

Comment: @fmw42 : Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 . Maybe an update will fix the problem but I need to check with owner of the server.

Comment: ImageMagick 6.6.0.4 is ancient. It is about 380 versions old. Upgrade as much as you can. I understand the different flavors of Linux are limited in how often they update ImageMagick